# Invoking javascript to modify a select element on a React form

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am trying to change the value of a *select* element on a web page that has been coded with React.

```
<select id="pickMenu" data-reactid=".6.0.3.4">
  <option value="1" selected data-reactid=".6.0.3.4.1.1">XS</option>
  <option value="2" data-reactid=".6.0.3.4.1.2">S</option>
  <option value="3" data-reactid=".6.0.3.4.1.3">M</option>
  <option value="4" data-reactid=".6.0.3.4.1.4">L</option>
  <option value="5" data-reactid=".6.0.3.4.1.5">XL</option>
</select>
```

The trouble I'm having is that, when I try to invoke some javascript to select another *option*, the modification seems to visibly occur in the browser but gets ignored by React when I post the form.

```
document.getElementById('pickMenu').value = 4;
```

I tried to trigger *click*, *input* and *mouseup* events manually but none of them end up reaching React.

So how can I get React to become aware of my modification ?

I should also add that I am using *browser.Document.InvokeScript(...)* as I am webscraping the site through a WebBrowser control but the problem is the same if I use my IE console.

Comment: You cannot modify your React components using regular JavaScript. I suggest reading the [React form documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't read HTML content in order to figure out something like a form active value, so changing the DOM representation won't work. Your best option is to simulate an event that actually changes the form the way a user would do, using [happen](http://github.com/tmcw/happen) or the [createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) API.